# Llamar varios eventos automáticamente

Tags: javascript, html, css

¿Cómo hago para ocultar ejecutar varios eventos al mismo tiempo?

Quiero ocultar todos los botones numéricos con *, por ahora al usar un id puedo llamarlo por js el evento y me lo oculta al acercar el mouse, pero quisiera que se ocultara el resto de botones.

```js
   $('#uno').hover(function(){
        $(this).val(" * ");
    }, function() {
        $(this).val(" 1 ");
      
    });

    $('#dos').hover(function(){
        $(this).val(" * ");
    }, function() {
        $(this).val(" 2 ");
    });
    $('#tres').hover(function(){
        $(this).val(" * ");
    }, function() {
        $(this).val(" 3 ");
    });
    $('#cuatro').hover(function(){
        $(this).val(" * ");
    }, function() {
        $(this).val(" 4 ");
    });
    $('#cinco').hover(function(){
        $(this).val(" * ");
    }, function() {
        $(this).val(" 5 ");
    });
    $('#seis').hover(function(){
        $(this).val(" * ");
    }, function() {
        $(this).val(" 6 ");
    });
    $('#siete').hover(function(){
        $(this).val(" * ");
    }, function() {
        $(this).val(" 7 ");
    });
    $('#ocho').hover(function(){
        $(this).val(" * ");
    }, function() {
        $(this).val(" 8 ");
    });
    $('#nueve').hover(function(){
        $(this).val(" * ");
    }, function() {
        $(this).val(" 9 ");
    });
    $('#cero').hover(function(){
        $(this).val(" * ");
    }, function() {
        $(this).val(" 0 ");
    });

    document.title = "ejemplo teclado";

    <!----- variable para imprimir numeros
    var answer_mode = 0;    

    <!----- función para limpiar la pantalla
    function clear1() {
        document.forms["teclado"].display.value = "";
    }
    
    function clear() {
        clear1();
    }

    function number(ch) {
        if (answer_mode) {
        clear1();
        answer_mode = 0;
        }    
        document.forms["teclado"].display.value += ch;
        var hoja=ch
    }
```

```css
.estilo {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  font-size:30px;
  color:blue
}
button {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<form name="teclado">

<input readonly="readonly" type="password" name="display" value="" size="8" style="text: Arial; font-size: 20pt; background-color:#58D3F7" >
<table>

<tbody>

<tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  
<td>  <input value=" 7 " onclick="number(7)" type="button" id="siete" class="estilo"></td>    
<td>  <input value=" 8 " onclick="number(8)" type="button" id="ocho" class="estilo"</td>
<td>  <input value=" 9 " onclick="number(9)" type="button" id="nueve" class="estilo"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>  <input value=" 4 " onclick="number(4)" type="button" id="cuatro" class="estilo"></td>
<td>  <input value=" 5 " onclick="number(5)" type="button" id="cinco" class="estilo"></td>
<td>  <input value=" 6 " onclick="number(6)" type="button" id="seis" class="estilo"></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>  <input value=" 1 " onclick="number(1)" type="button" id="uno" class="estilo"></td>
<td>  <input value=" 2 " onclick="number(2)" type="button" id="dos" class="estilo"></td>
<td>  <input value=" 3 " onclick="number(3)" type="button" id="tres" class="estilo"></td>
</tr>



<td><input value=" 0 " onclick="number(0)" type="button" id="cero" class="estilo"></td>

<td></td>

<td>  <input value="C" onclick="clear1()" type="button" class="estilo"></td>

<td></td>

<!---Mostramos en la URL el código ingresado, este es el que debes mandar a la BD como Script que pides-->
<button class="btn" type="ver">Mostrar URL</button>
```

Espero haber sido claro

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Son 3 pasos los que necesitamos.

1. Utilicé tu clase `estilo` para reducir el código de `hover` y `mouseleave`.
2. Entremos un poco en `HTML5`; le puse unos `data-number` a tus números para que al momento de reemplazar el valor por `*` an entrar, tengamos de dónde recuperarlo al salir.
3. Y por último con la misma clase `estilo`, ciclé todos los elementos para llegar a donde querías. Tuve que crear una nueva clase `c` para tu botón C, por que también se reemplazaba.

Revisa tu código, y elimina lo que ya no te sirva, recuerda que mientras menor sea el código, mejor es el programador.

Espero que te sirva

```js
$('.estilo').hover(function(){
    $('.estilo').each(function(){
      $(this).val(" * ");
    });
});

$('.estilo').mouseout(function(){
  $('.estilo').each(function(){
     let val = $(this).data('number');
      $(this).val( val );
  });
});

    document.title = "ejemplo teclado";

    <!----- variable para imprimir numeros
    var answer_mode = 0;    

    <!----- función para limpiar la pantalla
    function clear1() {
        document.forms["teclado"].display.value = "";
    }
    
    function clear() {
        clear1();
    }

    function number(ch) {
        if (answer_mode) {
        clear1();
        answer_mode = 0;
        }    
        document.forms["teclado"].display.value += ch;
        var hoja=ch
    }
```

```css
.estilo {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  font-size:30px;
  color:blue
}

.c {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  font-size:30px;
  color:blue
}

button {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<form name="teclado">

<input readonly="readonly" type="password" name="display" value="" size="8" style="text: Arial; font-size: 20pt; background-color:#58D3F7" >
<table>

<tbody>

<tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  
<td>  <input value=" 7 " data-number="7" onclick="number(7)" type="button" id="siete" class="estilo"></td>    
<td>  <input value=" 8 " data-number="8" onclick="number(8)" type="button" id="ocho" class="estilo"</td>
<td>  <input value=" 9 " data-number="9" onclick="number(9)" type="button" id="nueve" class="estilo"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>  <input value=" 4 " data-number="4" onclick="number(4)" type="button" id="cuatro" class="estilo"></td>
<td>  <input value=" 5 " data-number="5" onclick="number(5)" type="button" id="cinco" class="estilo"></td>
<td>  <input value=" 6 " data-number="6" onclick="number(6)" type="button" id="seis" class="estilo"></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>  <input value=" 1 " data-number="1" onclick="number(1)" type="button" id="uno" class="estilo"></td>
<td>  <input value=" 2 " data-number="2" onclick="number(2)" type="button" id="dos" class="estilo"></td>
<td>  <input value=" 3 " data-number="3" onclick="number(3)" type="button" id="tres" class="estilo"></td>
</tr>



<td><input value=" 0 " data-number="0" onclick="number(0)" type="button" id="cero" class="estilo"></td>

<td></td>

<td>  <input value="C" onclick="clear1()" type="button" class="c"></td>

<td></td>

<!---Mostramos en la URL el código ingresado, este es el que debes mandar a la BD como Script que pides-->
<button class="btn" type="ver">Mostrar URL</button>
```

Comment: ¡Genial!, si es que ando aprendiendo apenas HTML5 y pues aún no sé bien el uso de todos los elementos, total es excelente. Gracias!

Comment: Recuerda que si te sirvió, no olvides marcarla como correcta, en la palomita de la publicación. Saludos